# Return URL and SessionTimeout not working properly using ASP .Net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a class `CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute` and here i have created a method for return url if a logged out automatically when session timeout.

when it's automatically logged out when session timeout it's take return url. when i write correct credentials it's return view of Login Controller. it is not going two return url.

And another issue is when session timeout and come to login page and when i press browser's back it come to previous page, that was not possible. even it's not working when i logged out.

```
http://localhost:1563/?returnUrl=%2FElectricity
```

when i login it is not going to return url like `http://localhost:1583/Electricity`

it goes `http://localhost:1563/user`

Login Controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Example.com | Login";
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
            {
                string username = fc["username"].ToString();
                string password = fc["password"].ToString();
                var query = (from u in db.tbl_user
                             where u.USERNAME == username && u.PASSWORD == password
                             select u).FirstOrDefault();
                if (query != null){
                    Session["username"] = username;
                    Session["login"] = true;
                   return RedirectToAction("Index","User");
                }
                return View("Index");
            }
```

Class Name `CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute` :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["login"] == null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                filterContext.Result =
               new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
                 {
             { "action", "Index" },
            { "controller", "Login" },
            { "returnUrl", filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl}
                  });

                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

web.config :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" cookieless="false"></sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="1">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
```

Comment: show your Login controller Index get action

Comment: @EhsanSajjad , I have added Index get function of login controller.

Comment: Please do not use FormCollection for your model and using TempData is not the best idea either. I will post an answer shortly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using MVC, I do not recommend using FormCollection as the model being passed to your controller method. Sticking with the MVC pattern will help simplify a lot of things, especially as your application becomes more complex. So lets start with your login model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace YouProjectName.Models
{
    public class AccountLoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You do not have to decorate you model properties with attributes like `[Required]`, `[DataType]` and `[HidenInput]`, but I highly recommend using them as I will show you a couple of different ways you can render your view (also adding the required attribute is highly recommended so you do not have to check required fields individually in your controller).

With that said, lets take a look at how we can handle the model in the controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl = "")
{
    return View(new AccountLoginModel {ReturnUrl = returnUrl});
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountLoginModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var query = (from u in db.tbl_user
                 where u.USERNAME == model.Username && u.PASSWORD == model.Password
                 select u).FirstOrDefault();
    if (query != null){
        Session["username"] = model.Username;
        Session["login"] = true;

       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ReturnUrl))
       {
            return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
       }

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username and/or Password is incorrect");
    return View(model);
}
```

The `[HttpGet]` version of the `Index` method passes a new instance of the model to the view, while also capturing the returnUrl parameter that is passed to the method. In the `[HttpPost]` version of the `Index` method, it first checks `ModelState.IsValid`. All the properties on the model that are marked as `[Required]` are validated here. If it is not valid just return the model back to the view and the error messages will be displayed for the user. Lastly just check to see if `model.ReturnUrl` is empty. If it is not, redirect to the to the value in it, if not redirect to the UserController.

With the view, you have a couple of options. If you used the attributes to decorate your model properties, you could do something as simple as this:

```
@model YouProjectName.Models.AccountLoginModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Example.com | Login"; }

@Html.ValidationSummary()

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

With the call to `@Html.EditorForModel()`, the razor view will look at the model properties and render them based on the attributes applied to each property. You do not have to do it this way though. You can always manually add each input to maintain full control over the layout of the HTML elements. Something like this (just an example that uses Twitters bootstrap css):

```
@model YouProjectName.Models.AccountLoginModel

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Example.com | Login"; }

@Html.ValidationSummary()

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
}
```

The important part here is to make sure to add the `@Html.HiddenFor()` for the returnUrl inside the form. This way the return url gets posted back with the rest of the properties!

Comment: Thanks @Bobby Caldwell for your precious time, actually i am new ASP MVC pattern so i have no idea about that. Thanks again to give me great idea. I have another issue `Session Timeout`, i have mentioned above in web.config file. Problem is if i have set session timeout 15 but it automatically session timeout in few seconds. How can i set Session Timeout in a proper way ? Can you give me your idea for this ?

Comment: Well that probably has something to do with your custom CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute. MVC will automatically add the returnUrl to the URL when a users session expires, so it is safe to remove CheckSessionTimeOutAttribute. Try setting the timeout to 2880. Give it a try by removing your custom attribute for timeout, navigate to http://localhost:1583/Electricity then manually delete your cookies (search for localhost when removing cookies, that way you do not remove all your cookies!) then refresh the page. It will automatically add the returnUrl for you!

Answer (score 1):

@Manish, change login controller as below.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl = "")
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Smartmultiservices.in | Login";
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
        {
            TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
    {
        string username = fc["username"].ToString();
        string password = fc["password"].ToString();
        var query = (from u in db.tbl_user
                     where u.USERNAME == username && u.PASSWORD == password
                     select u).FirstOrDefault();
        if (query != null)
        {
            Session["username"] = username;
            Session["login"] = true;
            if (TempData["returnUrl"] != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TempData["returnUrl"].ToString()))
                return Redirect(TempData["returnUrl"].ToString());
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Wells, It's working. I have another issue as i mentioned above in `web.config` file. if i have set session timeout 15 but it automatically session timeout in few seconds. what to do ? please help me.